# ListView Binding from List

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I search over all internet but I didnt find an answer. I am new in MVVM and also pretty new in WPF.

I have defined method in one class where I search for USB devices (with help of another .dll library):

```
public void FindDevices()
    {
        _deviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorID, ProductID).ToArray();

        String[] deviceSNstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];
        String[] deviceManufacturerstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];
        String[] deviceProductstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];

        List<Devices> devices = new List<Devices>();
```

An later I become a nice List of devices.

In another class I want to bind this List in ViewModel class into ListView. How to do it? And I must also start method to find my devices "FindDevices".

My XAML ListView if defines so:

```
<ListView Name="DeviceGrid" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,10,15,35" ItemsSource="{Binding lvDevices}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridDevices">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DeviceId" Header="DeviceId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceId}" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ManufacturerId" Header="ManufacturerId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturerId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProductId" Header="ProductId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="SerialNumberId" Header="SerialNumberId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SerialNumberId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="HardwareVersionId" Header="HardwareVersionId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HardwareVersionId}" Width="130"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FirmwareVersionId" Header="FirmwareVersionId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirmwareVersionId}" Width="130"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DateOfManufaturedId" Header="DateOfManufaturedId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfManufaturedId}" Width="130"/>
            </GridView>
       </ListView.View>
```

So ItemsSource is defined. INotifyPropertyChanged I have defined over "ViewModelBase.cs":

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    #region Constructor

    protected ViewModelBase()
    {
    }

    #endregion // Constructor

    #region DisplayName

    public virtual string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    #endregion // DisplayName

    #region Debugging Aides

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }


    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

    #endregion // Debugging Aides

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChangedAll(object inOjbect)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in inOjbect.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(pi.Name);
        }
    }
    public virtual void Refresh()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChangedAll(this);
    }
    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.OnDispose();
    }

    protected virtual void OnDispose()
    {
    }



    ~ViewModelBase()
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} ({1}) ({2}) Finalized", this.GetType().Name, this.DisplayName, this.GetHashCode());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }


    #endregion // IDisposable Members

}
```

Also in Devices.cs I already define "set" an "get"

```
public class Devices : ViewModelBase
{

    private int deviceid;
    private string manufacturerid;
    private string productid;
    private string serialnumberid;
    private string hardwareversionid;
    private string firmwareversionid;
    private string dateofmanufacturedid;

    public int DeviceId
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceid;
        }
        set
        {
            deviceid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DeviceId");
        }
    }
```

(+ for ManufacturerId, ProductId, SerialNumberId, HardwareVersionId, FirmwareVersionId, ...)

What else I must have? :)

Comment: You bind them by using `{Binding}` xaml markup extension. And yes, you have to start method to find your devices :)

Comment: Bind the ListView`s ItemSource property to {Binding}

Answer (score 0):

in your viewmodel, set a property of type List by using your find method and bind it with XAML in the view.  ie. `ItemSource="{Binding MyList}"`.  Don't forget to use implement INotifyPropertyChanged and set your DataContext...
here is a link to several ways of setting datacontext for you
http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches

Comment: DataContext? Any example please :)

Comment: you must remember to set your view's datacontext to your viewmodel  one way, in the code-behind of your view, this.DataContext=new MyViewModel();  this sets the datacontext of your view to an instance of your view model.  you may also do this via XAML though, google it if you wish.  this basically tells your view what to bind to (the viewmodel)

Comment: Why I must "Bind" both? ItemsSource & DataContext?

Comment: In first class where I am searching for devices I have this loop which I want to run. But my ViewModel doesnt find it unless I change method in first class to static. But then I have problem with my .dll library,  which give me an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". What to do? :)

Comment: without seeing your entire code, it is hard to say.  sounds like you just need to instantiate (create) a new instance of the class first.  ie. MyClass myClass=new MyClass().  then, myClass.FindDevices();  sounds like the DLL you are using doesn't want it to be static, so you have to have an object reference, the myClass you just created.

Comment: I update my first post if helps anything :) And how I can get List from other method to my ViewModel?

Comment: in your viewmodel, have a List<Device> property, call the other method and have your other method return a List<Device>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to not understand you completely ...

My class where searching for USB devices. I just need a list of connected USB devices:

namespace Middleware
{
    public class USBmiddleware
    {
        private HidDevice[] _deviceList;
        public delegate void ReadHandlerDelegate(HidReport report);

```
    private const int VendorID = 0x453;
    private const int ProductID = 0x3FG;

    private static readonly int[] SupportedDeviceGrid = new[] { VendorID, ProductID };

    int nod; // number of devices



    public void FindDevices()
    {


        _deviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorID, ProductID).ToArray();

        String[] deviceSNstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];
        String[] deviceManufacturerstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];
        String[] deviceProductstring = new String[_deviceList.Length];

        //List<Devices> devices = new List<Devices>();

        List<Devices> mydevices = MyWildDevices();


        for (nod = 0; nod < _deviceList.Length; nod++)
        {
            bool boolSerialNumber = false;
            byte[] dataSerialNumber;
            boolSerialNumber = _deviceList[nod].ReadSerialNumber(out dataSerialNumber);

            bool boolManufacturer = false;
            byte[] dataManufacturer;
            boolManufacturer = _deviceList[nod].ReadManufacturer(out dataManufacturer);

            bool boolProduct = false;
            byte[] dataProduct;
            boolProduct = _deviceList[nod].ReadProduct(out dataProduct);

            if (boolSerialNumber == true)
            {
                deviceSNstring[nod] = FromHexString((String.Join("", dataSerialNumber.Select(d => d.ToString("X2")))));
            }
            else
            {
                deviceSNstring[nod] = "Error by Reading SerialNumber of device";
            }

            if (boolManufacturer == true)
            {
                deviceManufacturerstring[nod] = FromHexString((String.Join("", dataManufacturer.Select(d => d.ToString("X2")))));
            }
            else
            {
                deviceManufacturerstring[nod] = "Error by Reading ManufacaturerID of device";
            }

            if (boolProduct == true)
            {
                deviceProductstring[nod] = FromHexString(String.Join("", dataProduct.Select(d => d.ToString("X2"))));
            }
            else
            {
                deviceProductstring[nod] = "Error by Reading ProductID of device";
            }

            mydevices.Add(new Devices()
            {
                DeviceId = nod + 1,
                ManufacturerId = deviceManufacturerstring[nod],
                ProductId = deviceProductstring[nod],
                SerialNumberId = deviceSNstring[nod],
                HardwareVersionId = "test4",
                FirmwareVersionId = "test5",
                DateOfManufaturedId = "test6"

            });
        }

    }

    public static List<Devices> MyWildDevices()
    {

        List<Devices> DeviceList = new List<Devices>();

        return DeviceList;
    }

    public static string FromHexString(string hexString)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public static string ToHexString(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        foreach (var t in bytes)
        {
            sb.Append(t.ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }


}
```

}

And PageViewModel where I like to load list to my ListView

```
namespace ViewModel
```

{
    class Page2ViewModel : PageViewModelBase
    {

```
    public Page2ViewModel()
    {
        Heading = "Page 2";

        //new USBmiddleware().FindDevices();

        List<Devices> devices = USBmiddleware.MyWildDevices();
    }

    public override void ButtonContinueClick()
    {
        Page3ViewModel vm = new Page3ViewModel();
        Page3 p3 = new Page3();
        p3.DataContext = vm;
        Navigator.NavigationService.Navigate(p3);
    }

}
```

}

How to return List now? And later Bind into ListView? Maybe I am stupid, but until now I didnt use so much List, specially not in different classes and methods. Sorry and Thanks to helping me :)